# Conditional Statements Inside Stylesheet To Target IE

Tags: css

I'm familiar with the html conditional tags

```
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
```

Because of various issues I need to use a single stylesheet. So I cannot use the above solution. I can't find hacks that work to target only ie9 browsers so I need an alternative.

I remember seeing once a condition used in a stylesheet that only IE understood. Something with an @ sign and 'MS'. It was awhile ago.

Does anyone know about this? Can it be used for browser specific (ie only) styling?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: I said that conditional tags won't help me in this case because I have to use only one stylesheet.

Comment: Out of interest: Which problems do you anticipate, that you need to have specific styles for IE9?

Comment: There's an element that is off by 2px in ie, all versions.

Comment: Could you demonstrate that problem, possibly as a new question? I believe there could be better solutions than CSS hacks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this is about the BETA and PREVIEW's of IE9, but maybe these will work for the full release also?

http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/112904

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<!--[if IE 9]><div id="ie9"><![endif]-->
... your page here ...
<!--[if IE 9]></div><![endif]-->
</body>
```

with a css like

```
#ie9 #wrapper { background-color: blue; }
```

will make a blue background only in IE9, all other browsers won't find `<div id=ie9>` since its hidden in the comments. that should do the trick :)

See also [Wikipedia on Conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comments) for an in-detail explanation.