# How to write special css for IE in external css file using css conditional comments

Tags: css

As the title says how can we write special css for IE in external css file using css conditional comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional Statements Inside Stylesheet To Target IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639342/conditional-statements-inside-stylesheet-to-target-ie)

Comment: I only know of 1 way to do 'conditional comments' with external stylesheets, are there others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also invoke a stylesheet for different versions of Internet Exploer, versions older than a specific version, and using operators. [CSS-Tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) has a nice article demonstrating more possibilities.

Internet Explorer 9 or below

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Internet Explorer 6

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie-6.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: @Brian.Thanks. So this will only be applied for IE and ignores other browsers. Am I right?

Comment: "All Internet Explorer Versions" -> "IE 9 or below". IE 10 ignores conditional comments.